# Is it possible to extend the possible options for a material ui component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Let's say I have a Button whose colors I want to extend. Besides the ones that come with the component, I also want to give the possibility of having a success color which will make the button green. Is there a way of achieve such thing?

I tried a HOC, but with TypeScript it will trigger an error if I use a different color than the original. Perhaps I made it wrong.

Here's my code:

```js
import { Button, ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import { LuxButtonStyles } from './style';

type MaterialColor = 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'default' | 'inherit';
type CustomColor = 'info' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'success';

interface IProps {
    color?: MaterialColor | CustomColor;
}

const customColors = ['info', 'error', 'warning', 'success'];
const materialColors = ['primary', 'secondary', 'default', 'inherit'];

export function LuxButton(props: IProps & ButtonProps): JSX.Element {
    function throwError() {
        console.error(new Error('Color prop must be provided one of this values: primary, secondary, info, error, warning, success, default'));
        return <></>;
    }

    let color = props.color;

    if (!color) {
        color = 'default';
    }

    const isMaterialColor = materialColors.includes(color);
    const isCustomColor = customColors.includes(color);

    if (!isMaterialColor && !isCustomColor) { return throwError(); }

    if (isMaterialColor) {
        return <Button
            {...props}
            color={color as MaterialColor}>
            {props.children}
        </Button>;
    }

    const classes = LuxButtonStyles();
    return <Button
        {...props}
        className={classes[color as CustomColor]}>
        {props.children}
    </Button>;
}
```

`LuxButtonStyles` is a compilation of styles made with `makeStyles` that creates a specific style for each color that is not one that comes by default with the `Button` component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `makeStyles` to set custom css classes to components. [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

Comment: Yeah, but that's what I'm doing already. This is supposed to go on a design system and to be used in a lot of projects, so it makes sense to have the colors extended here and not in each project.

Comment: I mean, LuxButtonStyles is a compilation of styles made with `makeStyles`

Comment: So do you want to extend the attributes like `color="primary"`?

Comment: That's exactly it!